# Watchkit app include in two different targets

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I am trying to integrate a watchkit app into an existing application. Since we have an enterprise version for testing as well as the public app, there are two different application targets:

```
com.mycompany.productname
com.mycompany.internal.productname
```

I have the watchkit app building successfully on our internal target, but I cant get the same watchkit app linked to the application target.  This is the error that I receive:

```
Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier
```

I know it is because the WatchKit extension is supposed to have a bundle identifier prefixed by the application target's bundle identifier, but unfortunately these are not the same for the two targets, so my WatchKit extension cannot have them both as the prefix. Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure i understand completely. Why can't you do as the error says? Have both the watch extension and parent app with the same prefix. In our projects we have a separate scheme setup that we can switch between that handles these bundleID changes for us.

Comment: Since the app has two different targets, one for enterprise beta testing and one for production, it uses two different bundle identifiers. Thus, the watchapp can only match one of them. I am looking for a way that allows us to build for either target without having to switch bundle identifiers for the watchapp project depending on the target being built

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that. The bundleID, build numbers and version numbers must all match. The watch extension will have 'extension' in the bundleID though. If you want to avoid continual switching and even run both apps on the same device, this link will give you an idea on how to do that with schemes. http://www.swwritings.com/post/2013-05-20-concurrent-debug-beta-app-store-builds/

Answer (score 0):

You could add another WatchKit App target to your project and embed it in your other build target.

Xcode will create a new storyboard, Info.plist and some view controllers, but you can remove all these newly created files.

Then, duplicate your original WatchKit App's Info.plist, rename it, and point your second WatchKit App to this copy.

Both WatchKit Apps will now use the same files (storyboards, etc) and you will be able to use different bundle identifiers and provisioning profiles, since they each have their own Info.plist.

Please let me know if you'd like me to explain myself using screenshots.

Comment: Is this the only sane solution?

Comment: The same question - 2018 year. Is it the only solution. Additionally I want to ask what if I need to move the watchkit from one target to another one? Should I create another target too?